# XMLSyntaxError: Char 0x0 out of allowed range

Tags: python, python-3.x, lxml

I am trying to read a string with xml content using lxml library.

I encode the string to utf-16 converting it to byte, that is what the XML expects:

```
root = etree.XML(xml.encode('utf-16'))
```

This launches next error:

```
lxml.etree.XMLSyntaxError: Char 0x0 out of allowed range, line 2, column 3
```

Here is the xml encoded. The character selected is the one referenced in the error message:
[image]

And I can't see if the problem is in some character or I am not using correctly the library.

Comment: Can you post the xml string with markup? The screen shot rendering is not quite useful.

Comment: @Parfait: I have just marked the referenced error in the picture

Comment: The screenshot shows a UTF-16 encoded file which has then been further encoded as an escaped string (e.g. containing stuff like `\xff` as four bytes, instead of a single byte with value 0xFF), making it an invalid XML file.

Comment: @interjay: so, when I encode the xml string object to utf-16, python is including this "\" characters, but how can I avoid it?

Comment: Python isn't including these characters. It only shows them if you print the string representation (e.g. using `repr`). I don't know how you're generating the file shown above, but there's likely a problem there.